# On the solution of matrix equation

Tags: matrices

Suppose $N(t)$ be a family of bounded $n$-by$n$ matrices with $t>0$ such that

$N(s+h)=N(s)N(h)$ holds for all $s,h>0$

What kind of structure of the solution could enjoy?

Can one always have that $N(t)=e^{At}$ holds for some $A$?

This assumption seems too strong, for instance, $N(s)=0$ is some solution.

So what structure does the whole solutions enjoy?

Comment: Where do your $s, t$ and $h$ range? Where do the coefficients live? Presumably this will have an impact on what the answer should be. In particular because I don't really see why $M$ would have to be non-singular unless your $t$ is allowed to take negative values.

Comment: Non-singular isn't enough; how do you define $M^t$ if $M$ isn't diagonalizable? If its eigenvalues are not all positive reals? 

Comment: Also, what do you mean by a "bounded" matrix?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are already aware of this, but in response to the setup that you have, the following comes to mind: [One parameter semigroups](http://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/1999/one-parameter-semigroups-for-linear-evolution-equations/engel-nagel_one-parameter-semigroups.pdf)

The linked PDF discusses evolution equations of the form $f(s+t)=f(s)f(t)$ in great detail, and might prove helpful.

Comment: As I seen, it assumed that $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(0)=I$ , then the result is valid. But does it still work for only bounded condition?

Comment: I think you can adapt the proof for the 1-dimensional case. Sketch: (1) fix any time $T$, e.g. $T=1$, and call $N(1)=e^A$ (2) prove that $N(tT)=e^{tA}$ for $t\in\mathbb{N}_+$ and then for each $t\in\mathbb{Q}_+$ (3) if the partial solutions for two incommensurable $T_1$ and $T_2$ do not agree, use irrationality to find rational $a$, $b$ such that $t=aT_1-bT_2$ is small and $\left\Vert N(t) \right\Vert>M$ is large (4) depending on what you mean by "bounded", play with this $t$ and $M$ to find a contradiction.

Comment: This seems not true, because $0$  is also a solution

Comment: In the scalar case the solution $0$ is usually excluded, but I think you can easily add it back in if you wish: $0$ must be a simple eigenvalue (as $N(t)=N(t/2)^2$), thus simply change $e^A$ to $\begin{bmatrix}e^A & 0\\\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. By the way, since you're checking this discussion, do you mind explaining us what "bounded" means?

Answer (score 2):

As Thierry and Qiaochu have pointed out, it's not clear what exactly the question means.  Even so, maybe it's possible to say something helpful.

The question asks

> Can one always have that $N(t) = M^t$ holds for some non-singular $M$?

This doesn't quite make sense, so I'll interpret it as

> Must there exist a non-singular matrix $M$ such that $N(t) = M^t$ for all $t$?

I'm guessing this was the intention.

The answer is probably no.  (I say "probably" because the hypotheses on $N$ weren't stated precisely.)  It's even false for $n = 1$.  That is, there exist functions $N: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ satisfying 
$$
N(s + t) = N(s) N(t)
$$ 
for all $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$, but not of the form $N(t) = M^t$ for any $M > 0$.  The existence of such functions requires the axiom of choice.

This is a problem going back to Cauchy.  It's equivalent to consider the equation $f(s + t) = f(s) + f(t)$ (by putting $f(s) = \log N(s)$), and this is what's usually called "Cauchy's functional equation".  You can find information about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) and [here](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/12/pri_la_funkcia_ekvacio_fx_y_fx.html), for example.

Maybe you're happy to assume that $N(t)$ is continuous in $t$, in which case there's a genuine question about matrices to be answered.  But in the absence of precise hypotheses, I don't know what you're happy to assume.

Comment: True, but with any reasonable interpretation of the word "bounded" in the text, these solutions may be excluded: the graph of all non-linear Cauchy solutions is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$. – Federico Poloni 0 secs ago

Comment: What do you reckon the OP means by bounded?  The phrase s/he uses is "family of bounded n by n matrices".  Any n by n matrix, as a linear operator, is bounded.  So perhaps s/he actually means "bounded family of n by n matrices", i.e. that there's a _uniform_ bound on the entries of the matrices N(t).  (In that case, not everything of the form $M^t$ is a solution, e.g. if n = 1 and the single entry of M is greater than 1.)  I suppose that's the most plausible interpretation, but I'd prefer not to have to guess.

Comment: Yes, I agree that *uniformly* bounded seems the most reasonable interpretation. The other one that comes to my mind is essentially "continuous at 0 as a function of $t$", but his comment rules it out.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be the solution to a linear differential equation $\dot{N}(t) = A(t) N(t)$, with appropriate initial conditions. Then $N$ has the property you desire, but it cannot be represented as an exponential unless $A$ is independent of $t$. You can find this and more in books on linear system theory such as Jack Rugh's (http://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_system_theory.html?id=ffNQAAAAMAAJ).

I am not sure but I believe it is true that the converse also holds - under suitable technical conditions, if $N$ has the one-parameter semigroup property then it can be represented as the solution to a linear differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

I shall assume $N(s)$ depends continuously on $s$; otherwise there are many discontinuous solutions even in the one-dimensional case. After a change of basis, we may assume that
$$N(1)=\pmatrix{M&0\cr 0&Q},$$
where $M$ is nonsingular and $Q$ is nilpotent. Since all the matrices commute, we have the same block structure for all of them:
$$N(s)=\pmatrix{M(s)&0\cr 0&Q(s)}.$$

Since $Q(1)$ is nilpotent, and $Q(1)=Q(1/n)^n$, it is easy to see that $Q$ is nilpotent for every rational. This is possible only if $Q(s)$ is identically zero. Moreover, $M$ is always nonsingular: if $s<1$, then $M(1)=M(s)M(1-s)$, so $M(s)$ is nonsingular for $s<1$, and for $s>1$, we can use that $M(s)=M(s/n)^n$. Now continuity implies that $M(\epsilon)=M(1)^{-1}M(1+\epsilon)$ approaches the identity as $\epsilon\to 0$, and it follows that $M(s)$ must be of the form $\exp(As)$.